# Is there any single function to print an iterable's values?

Tags: python, iterator

Suppose I have an iterable:

`var = "ABCDEF"`

I get the iterable like this:

`it = itertools.combinations(var,2)`

Is there any single function to print all values of iterables like

`printall(it)`

rather than using the `for` loop?

Comment: Why is a `for` loop a problem?

Comment: I don't believe so, but I may be wrong...

Comment: Wait... you could make your own module with a custom function and install it using distilus.

Comment: you can convert your iterator to a list, list(it)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This rather depends what you want, if you want to print out all the values, you need to compute them - an iterable doesn't guarantee the values are computed until after they are all requested, so the easiest way to achieve this is to [make a list](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list):

```
print(list(iterable))
```

This will print out the items in the normal list format, which may be suitable. If you want each item on a new line, the best option is, as you mentioned, a simple for loop:

```
for item in iterable:
    print(item)
```

If you don't need the data in a specific format, but just need it to be readable (not all on one line, for example), you may want to check out [the `pprint` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html).

A final option, which I don't really feel is optimal, but mention for completeness, is possible in 3.x, where [the `print()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is very flexible:

```
print(*iterable, sep="\n")
```

Here we [unpack the iterable](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) as the arguments to `print()` and then make the separator a newline (as opposed to the usual space).

Comment: Also, it may be worth pointing out that once an iterator has been iterated through, it's consumed.

Comment: @JoelCornett Indeed. Although if you have produced a list, you can then iterate over that instead.

Comment: for print(*iterable) is a winner.

Comment: I would add that sep=os.linesep is preferable over sep="\n" as it's cross-platform

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `str.join` method and join each element of the iterable on a new line.

```
print('\n'.join(it))
```

Comment: +1, but it's worth noting this presumes the elements are strings. If not, [a generator expression or list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) will be needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use format which will allow each element to be formated as you please:

```
>>> print '\n'.join('{:>10}'.format(e) for e in iter([1,2,'1','2',{1:'1'}]))
         1
         2
         1
         2
  {1: '1'}
```

Each element does not need to be a string necessarily, but must have a `__repr__` method if it is not a string.

You can then easily write the function you desire:

```
>>> def printall(it,w): print '\n'.join('{:>{w}}'.format(e,w=w) for e in it)
>>> printall([1,2,'3','4',{5:'6'}],10)
         1
         2
         3
         4
  {5: '6'}
```

I am using a list, but any iterable would do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [chain()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) function from itertools to create iterator for var data and then just unpack using * operator of iterator

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> var = 'ABCDEF'
>>> print(*chain(var))
A B C D E F
>>> print(*chain(var), sep='\n')
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

If you just need to iterate over existing data and print it out again you can use star operator * for this

```
>>> print(*var)
A B C D E F
>>> print(*var, sep='\n')
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on a solution which iterates without a `for` loop *and* works for infinite iterators:

```py
from more_itertools import consume

def printall(it):
    consume(map(print, it))
```

Instead of the `for` loop we have `consume` here.
Note that in this case the iterator is consumed while printing.

This, of course, works for infinite iterators as well:

```py
from itertools import count

printall(count())
```

Just for fun. :)